# Making specific text in textarea bold

Tags: javascript, html

I am making an chatbox in which for displaying chat history I used textarea which is readonly.... what I want is to make the starting text "Me: " Bold

```
document.getElementById(messagearea).value = 
document.getElementById(messagearea).value + "\n <b>Me:</b>" + message1;
```

Any help?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), please.

Comment: I updated what I was trying...any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is `messagearea` a variable?

Comment: messagearea contains the id of textarea

Comment: It is easier to use a `div`to display the history and there you can use the `<b>Me:</b>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to format part of the text in a textarea. Instead place the text in a `<div>`.

```
<div id="messages" style="white-space: pre-wrap"></div>
```

With jQuery:

```
$('#messages').append("<div><b>Me:</b>" + message1 + "</div>")
```