# how to give bold styles to jquery variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div class="col-md-5 formdiv">
              <h4 class="form-title1">Private Comment Generator</h4>
                <form  id="form" class="private-comments-form">
                    <div class="row">

                            <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
                                <label for="sel1">Vendor :</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" style="font-weight:bold;" id="textbox3" />
                            </div>

        <script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#commentscopyBtn").click(function() {
  var ven =$("#textbox3").val();
  var prod =$("#textbox4").val();
    var text = "Thank you for "  + $("#textbox3").val() + "  " ; 

    text += $("#textbox4").val() + "\ you can call into our support line." ;
    $("#output").val(text);   
  });



  $('#btn').click(function() {
    /*Clear textarea using id */
    $('#output').val('');

    /*Clear all input type="text" box*/
    $('#form input[type="text"]').val('');
  });
});
</script>


                            <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
                                <label for="sel1">Product :</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" style="font-weight:bold;" id="textbox4"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
                                <label for="sel1">&nbsp;</label>
                                <input class="form-control js-textareacopybtn"  id="commentscopyBtn" type="button" value="Get Content" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
                                <label for="sel1">Copy Content :</label>
                                <textarea class="col-xs-12 js-copytextarea" id="output" name="textarea" ></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
                                <input type="button" class="reset " id="btn"  value="Reset" />  
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

Here I'm appending the values from text fields to TextArea, I want to add the bold style for that variable to highlight those values, please suggest a solution.

I want to know how to add a style for the appended text.

Comment: So, you want everything in the textarea to be bold, or just a specific word?

Comment: just specific word , the values which are appending from text  box

Comment: Then , it is not possible inside a textarea. Use a `div` or a `label` for this, and surround your word by `<em>...</em>` tags. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14092947/making-specific-text-in-textarea-bold

Comment: Thank You for the replay, I will try this option

Comment: Here's another related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580247/can-i-embed-html-formatting-inside-of-a-textarea-tag

Answer (score -1):

Give <b> for the text in variable before you append